# How to set up a new program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-analytics

I'm trying to write a small console program to get total events for different event actions from Google Analytics using the Google Analytics API and write them to a csv.

This is my first Java program ever, first time using Eclipse, and first time using the Google Analytics API.

I'm having some trouble getting started. The biggest problem is, I can't figure out which packages from the GA API I need to include in my import declarations.

For example, I'm trying to build a new DataQuery, but Eclipse can't resolve the type and I'm not sure how to search through the packages to see if I can find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've included the jar(s) in the build path, when typing a class name just type part of it and then press **ctrl+space** and autocomplete will suggest classes it can find (even if you haven't imported the package).

So try typing 'DataQuer' in the code and pressing **ctrl+space**. Your desired class should be among the first suggested. If it's not in the list, it means it can't find your class (most likely you haven't imported the necessary jars).

Edit: As it seems the problem is missing jars, you can import a jar file by right clicking the project, then Build Path -> Configure Build Path..., then go to the 'Libraries' tab, Add external jars... and browse to the desired jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a keyboard shortcut **crtl+shift+o** for importing the correct classes automatically. You can also do it manually by hovering over the error and clicking import.

Comment: Thank you Troubleshoot. Something else I can't figure out is how to add classpathentries. The Google Analytics API comes with what I think is an html file called classpath-include. It contains a list of locations for the different .jar files that the readme says are essential for programs made on any platform. Is there a way I can add all of these paths at once to my project without having to select each individual library?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the solution would be to create a sub-folder of the main project folder and place all the jars in there. Then right click your project, select properties, java build path, then go to the libraries tab, click add jars, then select the folder with the jars. Also, when your question has been answered then please accept an answer.